# Filezilla чужие сообщения пользователя в логи

Tags: логирование, ftp, ftp-сервер, filezilla

Суть вопроса такова: после запуска ftp сервера начинают подключаться левые люди, так вот в логах я не вижу чтобы у них при соединении запрашивало логин и пароль и они могут отправлять сообщения и какие-то команды. Вот скрин, где не запрашивает пароль и он отправляет команды(также бывают просто пишут всякую чепуху, то бишь имеют возможность писать сообщения сюда), и когда пишут сообщения сюда, то они тоже такие синие.

[image: Чужое]

А вот что происходит когда подключаюсь я, мои знакомые через filezilla, totalcommander, ftp.exe ну и т.п.(там сразу запрашивает USER и PASS)

[image: Моё]

Насколько это серьёзно, на что они могут повлиять(если могут) и как они это делают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К любому открытому *tcp-порту* вы можете подключиться следующим образом через программу *telnet*:

```
telnet myftphost.ru 22
```

И после успешного соединения вы можете писать всё что хотите. Это в идеальных условиях ни на что не влияет. Все данные которые вы пишете и которые **не** соответствуют командам выбранного вами протокола (в данном случае ftp) должны быть проигнорированы серверным программным обеспечением, а те команды которые **верные** относительно протокола должны быть успешно выполнены сервером. Это может быть опасно только в том случае если в вашем серверном ПО была обнаружена какая-то уязвимость которую можно проэксплуатировать. Но все уязвимости обычно устраняются вместе с обновлением ПО. По этой причине все программные продукты которые оказывают какие-то сетевые сервисы рекомендуется держать полностью обновленными, а если сервис не является публичным, то держать его ещё и за сетевым фильтром.

Команда *telnet* обычно используется системными администраторами для того что бы в режиме сырого tcp соединения продиагностировать какую-то службу. Вы сами можете попрактиковаться в этом - для этого достаточно соединиться по нужному порту с нужным вам хостом и вводить правильные команды. Сами команды у каждого протокола разные и их можно загуглить.

В вашем же случае такие соединения скорее всего создают *сканеры безопасности* или *завирусованные компьютеры*, которые сканируют из разных точек Интернета все что можно просканировать в Интернете. Делается это конечно же с целью взлома и тут надо быть на стороже (возможные меры описаны мной выше)